# USB passthrough to VM with maximum isolation from host

Tags: linux, usb, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm thinking of experimenting with some USB devices in a virtual machine (preferably QEMU). For security reasons, I don't want to let them interact with the host.

Things I've tried:

1. Doing nothing special. This leaves the host vulnerable before the VM starts and after the VM stops if the USB device is connected, and also for a brief moment after hot-plugging the device while QEMU is running, in the time until QEMU claims it.
2. Setting the `authorized_default` attribute of the port (`/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.4/usb3/authorized_default`) to `0`. Then the device does not interact with the host, apart from descriptors exchange, which is fine. However, QEMU also does not have access to the device. If I try to set the `authorized` attribute of the device (`/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.4/usb3/3-3/authorized`) to `1` while QEMU is running, the control does not go to the QEMU guest, but rather to the host. (And even if it went to the guest, the host would be vulnerable after the VM stopped or let go of the device in another way.)

In these experiments, I always used QEMU with either `-device usb-host,hostbus=3,hostport=3` to pass a physical port to the guest, or `-device usb-host,vendorid=0x04f3,productid=0x0235` to pass the device to the guest, the result was the same for both options in each case.

One (untested) solution that came to my mind would be to set up a USBIP server on a machine I don't care about and connect a USBIP client in the VM to this server, however that requires the VM guest to have network access and support USBIP. That might not be a problem, but I wish there was another way. (Now, I got a new idea that maybe a USBIP client implementation could be incorporated into a QEMU virtual device. That drops the guest requirements while keeping the host safe. Still, a single-machine solution would be preferable.)

Is there any way to achieve USB passthrough on a single machine securely?

**Edit:**
Another option that I found (and tested successfully) is passing through the entire USB controller. My laptop has two of them, each controlling two of the total four USB ports. Only one controller is used by needed built-in devices (touchpad, bluetooth). The other one is only used by a camera, which can be disconnected using firmware settings. This makes this controller the ideal candidate for pass-through. Unfortunately, both controllers share the same IOMMU group along with other PCI-e devices, so pass-through is not possible unless I bypass the IOMMU groups using the ACS override patch (e.g. in the `linux-zen` kernel), which may be a potential security risk (according to [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Bypassing_the_IOMMU_groups_(ACS_override_patch)) that links [this article](https://vfio.blogspot.com/2014/08/iommu-groups-inside-and-out.html), and [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/bvif8d/official_reason_why_acs_override_patch_is_not_in/) that explains why the patch is a really bad idea). Then, however, it works exactly as I needed.

**Edit 2:**
After reading more about the security and stability implications of the ACS override patch, I want to avoid it. I might take a look deeper into the USP/IP (or alternative) approach with a dedicated, *unsafe* machine that is connected via a dedicated, *unsafe* network to my *safe* host (with proper firewall) that translates the *safe* USB/IP packets with *unsafe* contents to the *unsafe* VM (and vice versa). Another option I might end up doing in the end would be to stick with the *doing nothing special* option as the devices I'll be experimenting with are not all that malicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve USB passthrough on a single machine securely?

*DISCLAIMER:* I can't comment on the absolute security of what I'm going to suggest, and if you're genuinely concerned for the safety/security of the host, then don't forget that [virtual machine escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine_escape) exploits are very real and do exist... If you're taking this seriously, then a physically separate machine is going to be your best option.

The closest way to achieve what you're asking (i.e: connect a USB device to a VM, with *close to zero* interaction with the host), is to use PCIe passthrough to connect a physical USB Root Hub directly to the VM - it's important that it's the PCIe device that you pass through (i.e: a *Root Hub*, or Controller), not a USB device (i.e: a standard *USB Hub*).

When done correctly, all of the associated USB ports and devices will "*disappear*" from the host, and will "*appear*" in the VM, percieved as a physical device (not a virtual root hub).

You may want to have a dedicated USB add-in card to provide this functionality - many will have a single root hub with multiple ports, but there is demand for cards with multiple root hubs (ideally one port per hub) for exactly this - passing "real" USB trees to VMs.

There are lots of resources about configuring this, but it's important to note, your system must be configured to enable the IOMMU, and it must be functional (e.g: [AMD-Vi or Intel's VT-d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel-VT-d))... many older or "*desktop*" motherboards do not support this properly.

Comment: That's the way I also mentioned in the edit and that I might end up using

Comment: Ah yes, apologies - I had distractions and wrote my answer over a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you isolate a Device from the host machine?

None that I know of (VMware here).

The host hardware device that can be passed through (USB normally) is always available to the host subsystem. Assigning it to the guest is just a logical assignment so the USB drive inserted is not seen by both host and guest.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a way to only authorize a USB device to QEMU, it might involve some kernel hackery though... In any case, I will probably end up passing through the whole USB controller, as described in the edited question and in the other answer. That will make the whole process easier. Thanks anyway!

Comment: There certainly is no native way to do what you want. VM Apps do not pass the whole controller through.